# VBA Scroll to top (not left)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a command that scrolls the current `ActiveCell` to the top of the page.

As `Activecell` is in column `C`, if I use the below code it moves `A` & `B` out of sight.

How do I use active cell to scroll up without moving A & B out of the field of view.

Thanks

```
Application.Goto ActiveCell, Scroll:=True
```

Comment: can't you use `Activecell.Select` ?  what is the purpose of this scroll ?

Comment: @Mikku: `Activecell.Select` will not move the active cell to the 1st visible row which I think is what the user is trying :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try:

```
Sub Scroll()
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't work, however it is 99% of what I need. I just needed to substitute Column with Row. Thanks